# For each element in X find index of largest without going over in Y

Tags: performance, matlab, sorting

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of the following algorithm. Given two arrays X and Y.

For each element of X find the index of the largest value in Y that does not exceed the value of the element in X. It is safe to assume X and Y are monotonically increasing (sorted) and that Y(1) is less than every value in X.
Also X is generally much larger than Y.

As an example given the following.

```
X = [0.2, 1.5, 2.2, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6.5];
Y = [0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0];
```

I would expect the output to be

```
idx = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
```

The fastest way I've come up with is the function below which fails to take advantage of the fact that the lists are sorted and uses a for loop to step through one of the arrays. This gives a valid solution but on the experiments I'm using this function for, nearly 27 minutes are spent here out of a total 30 minutes the analysis takes to run.

```
function idx = matchintervals(X,Y)
  idx = zeros(size(X));
  for i = 1:length(Y)-1
    idx(X >= Y(i) & X < Y(i+1)) = i;
  end
  idx(X >= Y(end)) = length(Y);
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How large are `X` and `Y` typically, out of curiosity?

Comment: X is on the order of 100,000 elements and Y is on the order of 10,000 elements. The problem is that there are about a lot of chunks of data that this size and the experiment needs to be run multiple times to adjust parameters.

Comment: @jodag So, does either of `X` or `Y` stay the same across those iterations? Can you re-use data across them?

Comment: @Divakar No X and Y are independent between iterations.

Comment: @jodag Okay, so did you try out the posted solutions?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks, I really appreciate the response and it is extremely fast on the given example and when `X=1:3:(4e5); Y=0:20:(4e5-1);` in the questions but it crashes with an indexing error when the largest value in Y is >= the largest value in X. For example `X=1:3:(4e5); Y=0:20:(4e5);` If you can get this issue resolved I'll select your answer.

Comment: @jodag Had to make few edits for that, check those out! gnovice's solution looks like the most efficient one.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks Divakar, I ended up picking gnovice's solution because it is the most efficient. All very nice answers upvotes on all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the fastest solution, it might end up being a simple while loop like so (which takes advantage of the fact that the arrays are sorted):

```
X = [0.2, 1.5, 2.2, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 5.8, 6.5];
Y = [0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0];

xIndex = 1;
nX = numel(X);
yIndex = 1;
nY = numel(Y);
index = zeros(size(X))+nY;  % Prefill index with the largest index in Y

while (yIndex < nY) && (xIndex <= nX)
  if X(xIndex) < Y(yIndex+1)
    index(xIndex) = yIndex;
    xIndex = xIndex+1;
  else
    yIndex = yIndex+1;
  end
end

>> index

index =

     1     2     2     2     3     4     4     4     5
```

This loop will iterate a maximum of `numel(X)+numel(Y)-1` times, potentially fewer if there are many values in `X` that are greater than the largest value in `Y`.

**TIMINGS:** I ran some timings with the sample data from a comment. Here are the results sorted from fastest to slowest:

```
X = 1:3:(4e5);
Y = 0:20:(4e5-1);

% My solution from above:
tElapsed =
   0.003005977477718 seconds

% knedlsepp's solution:
tElapsed =
   0.006939387719075 seconds

% Divakar's solution:
tElapsed =
   0.011801273498343 seconds

% H.Muster's solution:
tElapsed =
   4.081793325423575 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarking gnovice. It looks like all the answers give valid solutions and Divikar, knedlsepp and your solutions all are very efficient. Since yours is the fastest I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @jodag: I managed to speed it up even more by changing how I initialized `index`.

Answer (score 4):

A one-liner, but probably slower than the solution of gnovice:

```
idx = sum(bsxfun(@ge, X, Y'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sort` and few `masks` -

```
%// Concatenate X and Y and find the sorted indices
[sXY,sorted_id] = sort([X Y]);

%// Take care of sorted_id for identical values between X and Y
dup_id = find(diff(sXY)==0);
tmp = sorted_id(dup_id);
sorted_id(dup_id) = sorted_id(dup_id+1);
sorted_id(dup_id+1) = tmp;

%// Mask of Y elements in XY array
maskY = sorted_id>numel(X);

%// Find island lengths of Y elements in concatenated XY array
diff_maskY = diff([false maskY false]);
island_lens = find(diff_maskY ==-1) - find(diff_maskY ==1);

%// Create a mask of double datatype with 1s where Y intervals change
mask_Ys = [ false maskY(1:end-1)];
mask_Ysd = double(mask_Ys(~maskY));

%// Incorporate island lengths to change the 1s by offsetted island lengths
valid = mask_Ysd==1;
mask_Ysd(valid) = mask_Ysd(valid) + island_lens(1:sum(valid)) - 1;

%// Finally perform cumsum to get the output indices
idx = cumsum(mask_Ysd);
```

Comment: @gnovice Yeah that was an issue with it. Should be corrected now with the edits.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar idea as *Divakar*. This basically finds the insertion points of the values in `X` after the values of `Y` using the stable `sort`. 
Both `X` and `Y` need to be sorted for this to work correctly!

```
%// Calculate the entry points
[~,I] = sort([Y,X]);
whereAreXs = I>numel(Y);
idx = find(whereAreXs)-(1:numel(X));
```

You can view the values of `X` and the corresponding values of `Y` that don't exceed the `X`-values via:

```
%%// Output:
disp([X;Y(idx)]);
```

Comment: This definitely wins in elegance but is ever so slightly slower than gnovice's solution.

Comment: @jodag: From a theoretical standpoint *gnovice*'s answer is also how this should be implemented in a low-level language. And nowadays MATLAB loops perform quite well, so this is certainly a good way. (However: Which data sizes did you test? Running the test data in *gnovice*'s answer my solution performs 25% faster on my R2014a machine.)

Comment: @knedlsepp: I updated how I was initializing `index` and cut my time by more than half. `repmat` it seems is rather inefficient. :)

Comment: @gnovice: It's great to see a solid loop-approach outperform all the vectorization-shenanigans.